# Argument not optional when calling sub-procedure that passes dict as a value

Tags: excel, vba

My question is a little different here because I am trying to call a sub-procedure that has passed a dictionary as a parameter and it keeps returning the error 'Argument not optional'. Please help!

```
Sub Code1() 
  Call sub_input
End Sub 


 Sub sub_input (dicDat as Dictionary) 
 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws =ActiveSheet
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim vTemp As Variant
 Range("rInputStart").Parent.Calculate
 vTemp =Range(Range("rInputStart").Offset(1),_
    Range("rInputStart").End(xlDown).Offset(0,2)).value

 Dim price as Long  
 Dim currency As String: currency = vbNullString
 Dim exchangeRate as String: exchangeRate = vbNullString 
 Dim remark as String: remark = vbNullString 

  For j =1 To 10

       price = price & dicDat ("price" & CStr (j))&"|"
       price = price ("rPriceManual").value 
       currency = currency & dicDat("dl_currency"&CStr(j))&"|"
       exchangeRate =(exchangeRate & _ 
                      dicDat("exchange_rate"&CStr(j))&"|")/100 
       Remark= remark & dicDat("remarks"&CStr(j))&"|"

       For i =LBound(vTemp,1)ToUBound(vTemp,1)
          If vTemp(i,1)="currency"And dicDat(dl_currency)<> vbNullString _ 
          Then
             vTemp(i,3)= currency
          Endif 
           If vTemp(i,2)="remark"Then
              vTemp(i,3)=Remark
          EndIf
           If vTemp(i,2)="exchangeRate"Then
              vTemp(i,3)= exchangeRate
          EndIf
      Next i
   Next j
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a scripting.dictionary object to pass over to the sub.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Code1()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    dict.Item(10) = "abc"
    dict.Item(11) = "bcd"
    dict.Item(12) = "cde"

    sub_input dict
End Sub

Sub sub_input(dicDat As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim k As Variant

    For Each k In dicDat.keys
        Debug.Print k & " - " & dicDat.Item(k)
    Next k

End Sub
```

If you prefer late-binding, use `dim dict as object` then `set dict = createobject("scripting.dictionary")`.

> <sub>To use this code, go into the VBE's Tools, References then locate **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** and put a check beside it to include this library in your project. Library references like this are on a project-to-project basis, not a computer-to-computer basis. If you run your workbook on another computer, it will be carried across.</sub>

Comment: Can you see how dict is created in Code1, populated and then passed on to sub_input as the dicDat parameter where it was output to the VB's Immediate window? The code shown above should run by itself and output to the VBE's Immediate window.

Comment: Ahhhh I see it now. But that means I have to manually add all the items into the dictionary right? Can I clarify, is 10 referring to the keys and 'abc' referring to the value?

Comment: Well you said you already had a dictionary and there is no limit to the number of times it can be passed around. I'm sorry, but give the new partial information I cannot be more specific. Perhaps you can call this question closed and start a new question with specific details.

Answer (score 1):

You have called the sub `sub_input` but you are calling `sub_book` also `sub_input` requires a parameter `sub_input(dicDat as Dictionary)` but you are not adding a parameter to your `call` code.

**For example:**
if you called a sub `sub Test` but then add `(name as string)` next to it to make `Sub Test(Name as string)` you are making a variable that is necessary to run the sub. If you wanted to call this sub you would need to call it with a value to give the `Name` variable as it is a string you would need to surround that with "". as an example one way you could call this is `call Test("Geoff")` `"Geoff"` being the `name string`

The error you are getting is because you have not called your sub with nol value to the `dicDat` parameter. your code should look like: `call sub_input(TestValue) then that gives your 'dicDat' a value

For a more detailed explanation of argument not optional errors see [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/argument-not-optional)

My suggestion is at the top of **every** module/class/sheet where you are going to add code type `option explicit` at the top and then you will find any typos on names or subs

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry it's my bad cos I forgot to change from the previous code I was using. What does it mean by parameter? Does it mean I just put dicDat behind the call sub_input procedure?

Comment: No worries.I shall edit my answer to make it a bit clearer